# Docker volumes that share the same parent?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a docker based WordPress development environment and I want to be able to have a folder structure like this:

```
.
|
--wp-data
|
--wp-content
|
--plugins
|
--themes
```

where plugins and themes are also inside wp-content

this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - ./wp-data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: wordpress
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content/
            - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/
            - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    wp-data:
    wp-content:
    themes:
    plugins:
```

the wp-data and w-content are created ok
but the nested themes and plugins arent

what im missing?

Regards

Comment: What is the use case behind using separate volumes for themes and plugins as they are contents within the wp-content folder?

Comment: because im only interested in control versioning the themes and plugins folder, and im soooo new to the WordPress development ecosystem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing volumes. In your `docker-compose.yml` you create `bind mounts` for each service - that means you mount a particular directory of the host into containers.

At the same time you are declaring a section `volumes` where explicitly declare volumes with the same names, but **they are never used** and created as empty directories.

Of you want to create and use **volumes**, you need to rewrite your `docker-compose.yml` in the following manner:

```
services:
    ...
    db:
        ...
        volumes:
            - wp-data:/var/lib/mysql
        ...
    wordpress:
        volumes:
            - wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content/
            - themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/
            - plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/
volumes:
    wp-data:
    wp-content:
    themes:
    plugins:
```

This will enable volumes, but you still need a way to put data from host into them (like `docker cp` for example).

From the other hand, of you **intended to use bind mounts**, you need to completely remove ending `volumes:` section not to get confused.

Comment: Could you please explain to me the diff between the container volumes and the top level volumes? i try to find that info in the docker compose docs but or i dont find it or isnt very well explained.

Comment: There are no "container volumes". Volumes can be external (created explicitly by `docker volume create`) or they can be created automatically implicitly but `docker-compose`. The second option is well suited for cases when you just need to exchange data between services in container; while persisting data between sessions is better done with external volumes.